# Connect-mongo sessions not being deleted automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session

I have an application using NodeJS, Express, MongoDB and connect-mongo.

My issue is that sessions don’t seem to be automatically deleted from MongoDB when they expire, so the db size grows until the disk is full.

The developer of connect-mongo [wrote a comment](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/27#issuecomment-5133845):

> connect-mongo will ask MongoDB to remove all the sessions that have
>   expired before the current date.

But this doesn’t seem to be happening in my case.

My configuration is:

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

var sessionStore = new MongoStore({db: 'myappsession'});

var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "myappsecret", store:sessionStore }));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

And I’m currently running the following versions:

- **node:** 0.7.0-pre
- **connect-mongo:** 0.1.7
- **express:** 2.5.2
- **connect:** 1.8.5

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You haven't set a [`clear_interval`](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#options) for your sessions .. the connect-mongo default is -1 (or "never"):

> `clear_interval` Interval in seconds to clear expired sessions (optional, default: **-1**). Values <= 0 disable expired session clearing.

Example of removing expired sessions every hour (3600s):

```
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({
     db: 'myappsession',
     clear_interval: 3600
});
```

You should also make sure you have set a `maxAge` on your sessions to they actually expire (eg using 1 day):

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: "myappsecret",
    cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    store:sessionStore
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Stennie, that's a great help. Regarding the maxAge setting, should that be specified in seconds or milliseconds? For example, new Date(Date.now() + 86400) or new Date(Date.now() + 86400 * 1000)?

Comment: @KevanStannard: Sorry, botched the maxAge .. corrected example above.  You're right, it should be milliseconds.  I got sidetracked thinking of expiry date.

Comment: `connect-mongo`'s new default is 2 weeks, not "never".   And the setting lives under `ttl`  https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

Answer (score 6):

I don't know from where the `clear_interval` options was taken but I'm looking at the code of the [latest version](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/master/src/index.js):

```
class MongoStore extends Store {
 constructor(options) {
  options = options || {}

  /* Fallback */
  if (options.fallbackMemory && MemoryStore) {
    return new MemoryStore()
  }

  super(options)

  /* Options */
  this.ttl = options.ttl || 1209600 // 14 days
  this.collectionName = options.collection || 'sessions'
  this.autoRemove = options.autoRemove || 'native'
  this.autoRemoveInterval = options.autoRemoveInterval || 10
  this.transformFunctions = computeTransformFunctions(options, true)

  // ...

setAutoRemoveAsync() {
  const removeQuery = {expires: {$lt: new Date()}}
  switch (this.autoRemove) {
    case 'native':
      return this.collection.createIndex({expires: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 0})
    case 'interval':
      this.timer = setInterval(() => this.collection.remove(removeQuery, {w: 0}), this.autoRemoveInterval * 1000 * 60)
      this.timer.unref()
      return Promise.resolve()
    default:
      return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

So the correct way to set auto remove based on that code seems to be:

```
const store = new MongoStore({
  url: "put db connection string here ...",
  autoRemove: 'interval',     
  autoRemoveInterval: 60 * 24 // In minutes. Default
})
```

I dont see any trace of a `clear_interval` option, so it seems to me the suggested solution would have no effect ...

Comment: My original answer was for the current `connect-mongo` version in 2012. Things have definitely changed since then, but the answer worked at the time :)