# Ended sessions are not being destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, keystonejs, connect-mongo

My application is using [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo), [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), [keystone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone) and [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) handling login and user sessions.

However, when a session ends (user logs out or closing the browser window) the session is not removed from the MongoDB session store.

Here's my middleware setup:

```
var express = require('express')
    , path = require('path')
    , cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , passport = require('passport')
    , session = require('express-session')
    , mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
    , compression = require('compression')
    , favicon = require('serve-favicon')
    , config = require('../config')
    , flash = require('connect-flash');

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', parameterLimit: 52428800, extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET));
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', config.get('staticContentPath')), {
    maxAge: (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) * 1000 
}));

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hrs
    },
    store: new mongoStore({
        url: config.get('mongo')
    })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

The collection name for sessions in MongoDB is *app_sessions*. A search in my dependency tree reveals that this is handled by the Keystone CMS.

Also the cookie name is *keystone.sid*

This is my Keystone config:

```
var config = require('../../lib/config')
    , keystone = require('keystone');

module.exports = function(app){

    keystone.init({
        'app': app,
        'port': config.get('keystone').port,
        'brand': config.get('sitename'),
        'views': app.get('views'),
        'view engine': app.get('view engine'),
        'custom engine': app.get('custom engine'),
        'auto update': false,
        'session': true,
        'session store': 'mongo',
        'auth': true,
        'user model': 'Account',
        'cookie secret': process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
        'compress': true,
        'frame_guard': 'deny',
        'mongo': config.get('mongo')
    });

    keystone.import('../../lib/models');
    keystone.start();
};
```

And finally some example session objects from MongoDB:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "GUL2jwhCvqZHO7Gqy8KCHod1qJmrl6j4", 
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"_garbage\":\"2016-08-17T13:01:53.475Z\",\"guestPageViews\":1,\"flash\":{}}", 
    "expires" : ISODate("2016-08-31T13:01:57.642+0000")
},
{ 
    "_id" : "C-4cuoyIGHgYM8hLGhQVOv3bRwChwkxq", 
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"_garbage\":\"2016-08-17T13:02:44.000Z\",\"guestPageViews\":1,\"flash\":{}}", 
    "expires" : ISODate("2016-08-31T13:02:51.473+0000")
},
{ 
    "_id" : "foE9ewU3eoJXIzkW97GSbMGNzFt2W4ww", 
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"_garbage\":\"2016-08-17T13:04:35.294Z\",\"guestPageViews\":1,\"flash\":{}}", 
    "expires" : ISODate("2016-08-31T13:04:38.979+0000")
},
{ 
    "_id" : "P8ugG4TFHJAuCzNS9aCMSybIS25uFtL1", 
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"userId\":\"56cadedbc580346a1bd0ee0c\",\"_garbage\":\"2016-08-17T23:57:03.615Z\",\"flash\":{}}", 
    "expires" : ISODate("2016-08-31T23:57:05.203+0000")
}
```

Can you spot why the sessions would not be destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

> Why user is logged in even after closing browser?

Obviously because its is a good feature. to maintain a session even after  browser is closed.  but any how If you want to expire session on closing of browser then you can **set the maxAge to -1**

> Why it is not removing the session data even after logged out?

I think thats what developer of keystone.JS might have chosen. I was just looking at **signout** function in the keystone/lib/**session.js**.

Here it is calling **req.session.regenerate**.

probably it should have called  **req.session.destroy** instead. I just tried to do that change and test. but still I could see the sessions in Database.  Then I think. the solution is [clear_interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081741/connect-mongo-sessions-not-being-deleted-automatically)

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand how sessions are supposed to work then. I was under the impression that stored sessions should be deleted when the session ends, but you are saying that as per design, they are kept in the session store, so they can be reused?

Comment: no I havent sid that.? did you tried clear_interval suggestion.? I tired but could not get success.

Comment: I didn't say, that you said, that I didn't understand sessions. I said that :-) I'm just starting to think that I should leave the sessions as they are and keep them in the session store. It is probably how it is supposed to work.

Comment: hahaha, true, the only issue you will face is when servre shuts down . users will forced to login.